# Allow php in wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to use the following code in my wordpress. How can I do that?

```
<?php 
$theme_name = get_template();
$directory = "wp-content/themes/" . $theme_name . "/pdf/ECE340/";
$pdfs= glob($directory . "*.pdf");
foreach($pdfs as $pdf)
{
$link= substr($pdf,48,90);
?>
<a href="<?php echo $pdf; ?> "><?php echo $link; ?></a>
<?php
echo "\n\n";
echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: create as shortcode or put a code in template in wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the answer (taken from [here](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2011/04/11/executing-php-inside-a-wordpress-widget-without-any-plugin/)):

```
add_filter('widget_text','execute_php',100);
function execute_php($html){
     if(strpos($html,"<"."?php")!==false){
          ob_start();
          eval("?".">".$html);
          $html=ob_get_contents();
          ob_end_clean();
     }
     return $html;
}
```

Copy the above function at the end of your functions.php file.

But the **best soluttion** will be to create a custom template instead of using PHP in pages/widgets/posts. You will find more about wordpress custom templates [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates).

Answer (score 0):

Login to your admin panel. Click on `Appearance -> Editor` from left side menu. Then find the `Template` where you want to add the PHP code from right side menu. Then you can add your PHP code in the editor.

NOTE: Make sure do backup before you do any editing. I'm not responsible for your mistakes.